# Immutable borrow tied to mutable borrow causes "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time"

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutability

I am learning Rust by exercise. In this file the goal is to update cells as in a spreadsheet: when a value changes, all cells that are derived from it have to be recalculated. Here, those are called that cell's parents.

Updating a cell value proves no problem, but updating the parents gets me fighting the borrow checker. When I have retrieved the cell from a `HashMap` and updated the value, I no longer need a mutable reference - so I tried wrapping it in an immutable reference instead. That way I only have to find it once.

But it seems Rust figures since I originally got my immutable reference from a borrowed `&mut self`, it must still be tied to it. This obviously prevents me from reusing `self` a second time.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Cell {
    value: i32,
    parents: Vec<u32>,
}

pub struct Sheet {
    table: HashMap<u32, Cell>,
}

impl Sheet {
    pub fn set_value(&mut self, identifier: u32, new_value: i32) {
        let mut updated_cell: Option<&Cell> = None;
        if let Some(cell) = self.table.get_mut(&identifier) {
            let Cell { value, .. } = cell;
            *value = new_value;
            updated_cell = Some(cell);
        }
        if let Some(cell) = updated_cell {
            recalculate(self, &cell.parents);
        }
    }
}

fn recalculate(_sheet: &mut Sheet, _cells: &[u32]) {}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:20:16
   |
16 |         if let Some(cell) = self.table.get_mut(&identifier) {
   |                             ---------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
22 |             recalculate(self, &cell.parents);
   |                         ^^^^  ------------- first borrow later used here
   |                         |
   |                         second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I want to know if there is a solution which avoids searching a second time or taking an unnecessary vector copy. I have tried to adjust the code many times, but not all of the syntax is yet clear to me yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust is protecting you from a potentially dangerous situation. There is nothing in `recalculate`'s signature to guarantee that it won't mutate `sheet` in such at way that the references in `cells` become invalid. For example `recalculate` *could* delete some cells and then the references in `cell.parents` would be dangling pointers.

You probably need to pass a clone of the parent cells instead:

```
if let Some(cell) = updated_cell {
    let parents = cell.parents.clone();
    recalculate(self, &parents);
}
```

Alternatively, you may need to consider a different data model, which separates the mutability of individual cells from the mutability of the overall structure. For example, you could wrap cells in a `std::cell::Cell` or `std::cell::RefCell`, and pass an immutable reference to the `Sheet`.